# Xcode Server "Build Service Warning An unexpected error occurred"

Tags: osx-server, xcode-server

"Without any reason" my Xcode build server showed "An unexpected error occurred" after integrating a bot. Additionally no build products were shown after integration.

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 0):

The error was my own fault. To give my after integration scripts access to the build products I had changed the file permissions of `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations` and `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets` to `755`. Thus the server was not able to write the two directories anymore. By changing back the permissions to `775` the error went away.